# Override a Styled Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I've created a `Button` component in my React app using TS and Styled Components. For simplicity, here are the styles:

```js
const Button = styled.div`
    background: #fff;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 4px;
`
```

In a **separate page**, I'm using this button, but want to change the background color and the width. I assumed I could create my `SecondaryButton` with the following styles.

```js
const SecondaryButton = styled(Button)`
    width: 40px;
    background: red;
`
```

I've imported the `Button` component into my second file, so it's accessible. The `SecondaryButton` is correctly inheriting all of the `Button` styles, but the overridden styles aren't applying or even showing in the browser console.

How can I extend a styled component and add new styles to it? I'd like to avoid creating an additional component for this one-time use.

Styled-Components v6.1.6

React v18.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a `className` prop to the parent component before you can properly override the styling. Example:

#### Button.tsx

```js
interface IProps extends ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
   className?: string;
   children?: React.ReactNode;
   onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
}

export default function Button({ ...props }: IProps) {
  const { className, children, onClick } = props;

  return (
    <ButtonWrapper
      className={className}
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      {children}
    </ButtonWrapper>
  );
}

const ButtonWrapper = styled.div`
  //css goes here
`;
```

---

#### HomePage.tsx

```js
import Button from 'Button';

*/.../*
return(
  <SecondaryButton />
)

const SecondaryButton = styled(Button)`
  //new CSS
`
```

Reference: https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#styling-normal-react-components

> If you use the `styled(MyComponent)` notation and `MyComponent` does not render the passed-in `className` prop, then no styles will be applied. To avoid this issue, make sure your component attaches the passed-in `className` to a DOM node: